# How to format text infront of a datalabel in highchart?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, label

I'm new to highchart and are currently trying to place text infront of a datalabel

in highchart you can format data to that a unit appears after the data

```
plotOptions: {
   series: {
       dataLabels: {
           enabled: true,
           format: {y} mm'
         }
     }
},
```

the following will place `mm` after all datalabels(example `144mm`), however I wish to place the label in front of the datalabel(```mm144``)

Reason being I wish to display a dollar sign in front of my data(e.g `$100` would show up)

How can I accomplish this
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any obstacles to adding custom text at front of the value while defining format property.

`format: '$ {y}'`

You can also use the formatter callback to display wherever you want in the dataLabel.

```
  formatter() {

    return `custom text ${this.y}`
  }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pkv0w8r2/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.formatter